# How to retrieve data of a key in dictionary which is nested in list simultaneously

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-lists

```
data = [
    {
        'name1': 'aaa',
    },
    {
        'name2': 'bbb',
    },
    {
        'name3': 'ccc',
    },
    {
        'name4': 'ddd',
    }
]
```

Now how can I retrieve data of key >>name1   (i.e aaa ) with index no. of the list simultaneously.

Comment: What would be the expected output? Also showing what you have tried so far can help provide you with a better answer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't understand what the difficulty is. Do you know how to write code that gets that key from a dictionary? Do you know how to write code that gets one of the elements from a list? Since the elements in your list are dictionaries, there should be no problem, then. Just do both things.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You access list with index as `int`, you access a dict with index as the key, no matter the type

```
data = [
    {'name1': 'aaa', },
    {'name2': 'bbb', },
    {'name3': 'ccc', },
    {'name4': 'ddd', }
]

x = data[0]['name1']
print(x)  # aaa
```

---

Example with key type `int`

```
data = [{'name1': 'aaa'}, {0: 'ddd'}]
x = data[1][0]
print(x)  # ddd
```

Answer (score 0):

Method

- Use enumerate to provide index of each dictionary as you loop.
- Use dictionary.items() to retrieve key, value pairs of each dictionary

**Code**

```
def get_value(data, key):
        ' Retrieves index of dictionary and value with key key'
        for i, d in enumerate(data):
            for k, v in d.items():
                if k == key:
                    return i, v    # return index and value of dictionary
```

**Test**

```
print(get_value(data, 'name1'))
# Output: (0, 'aaa')
```